# Is it possible to make a website force install a chrome extension?

Tags: web, automation

My website necessarily needs a certain chrome extension to run, is it possible to code something that automatically installs the extension without the usual guide to add it?

It doesn't matter which code this is possible in, I would just like to know if it is possible and how I would be able to do it.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I assume you still want/need the popup that asks the user if they want to install the extension? If not, you're creating malware

Answer (score 0):

From a Chrome extension perspective, it's impossible to install a Chrome extension on the client computer itself automatically.
The only thing you can do is to make an announcement and a link to install that extension.
Otherwise, you have to make malwares to automatically install something on the client's computer without his permission